# I want to prevent the localstorage from clear my objects on reload and adding new entries in my form

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How do I prevent the local storage from being deleted after reload and insert a new entry from my input fields? I want to display the data that I saved in a list in HTML.

```js
// when I add new items in my form and submit it, the old entries in local-storage gets deleted
let datas = [];

const addEntry = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = {
    id: document.querySelector("#date").value,
    situation: document.querySelector("#situation").value,
    mood: document.querySelector("#mood").value,
    special: document.querySelector("#special").value,
    expectations: document.querySelector("#expectations").value,
    fulfilled: document.querySelector("#fulfilled").value,
  };
  datas.push(data);
  console.log(datas);
  document.querySelector("form").reset();
  localStorage.setItem("smokeEntries", JSON.stringify(datas));
};

let content;

//get object and save in array variable
   
const getEntriesFromLocalStorage = () => {
  content = [JSON.parse(this.localStorage.getItem("smokeEntries"))];
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", addEntry);
});
```

Comment: If I'm correct you are basically resetting the same property in localStorage by always using the smoke-entries key. I believe there are two solutions, either you save each data field in its own property. Solution two (the best solution imo), you grab the old smoke-entries and modify only what you want to modify. Correct me if I understood you wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I will try it. 
But for further clearance: I want to add more objects to the existing object in  the localstorage. 
The problem is here that, when I reload at first I bind  the existing object from the session before in a variable.  But if I add new entries via the form, the old ones disappear. 
Maybe that clears a little bit the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't try to keep two arrays (`datas` and `content`) in sync as it can cause inconsistency problems like this where you're using one to update and store information in state management and the other displayed visually are out of sync. I'd suggest combining them like this:

```
let content = [];

const addEntry = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = {
    id: document.querySelector("#date").value,
    situation: document.querySelector("#situation").value,
    mood: document.querySelector("#mood").value,
    special: document.querySelector("#special").value,
    expectations: document.querySelector("#expectations").value,
    fulfilled: document.querySelector("#fulfilled").value,
  };
  content.push(data);
  document.querySelector("form").reset();
  localStorage.setItem("smokeEntries", JSON.stringify(content));
};

const getEntriesFromLocalStorage = () => {
  content = [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("smokeEntries"))];
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", addEntry);
});
```

There also may be some problem with setting content (because we're wrapping it in brackets (`[]`) but it may already be an array -- should be pretty obvious after you run it, remove the brackets if it turns into nested arrays) but I haven't ran the code. Also note that for `content` to load "state" you'll need to call `getEntriesFromLocalStorage()` before using the state (or possibly trigger a re-render after).

Comment: @Pasquale did you try this?